# Creating a connection type in AWS AppSync to retrieve data from Aurora Serverless

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, amazon-aurora

so I have a Aurora Serverless DB in Amazon RDS. I would like to use this within GraphQL and set up connections between certain types. I.e, a User could have a list of Followers and that's used with a UserFollowerConnection type. What I would like this to do is paginate and only retrieve maybe 10 items at a time, and keep track of the nextToken. I was able to do this successfully with DynamoDB tables but I am trying to replicate the same implementation with RDS.

My schema looks something like this:

```
type User {
    userId: String!
    userName: String!
    fullName: String!
    displayName: String!
    email: String!
    followers(limit: Int, nextToken: String): UserFollowerConnection
}

type UserFollower {
    userId: String!
    followerId: String!
    dateFollowed: AWSDateTime!
}

type UserFollowerConnection {
    items: [UserFollower]
    nextToken: String
}
```

My current resolver implementation for DynamoDB looks something like this:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        ## Provide a query expression. **
        "expression": "userId = :id",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":id": {
                "S": "$ctx.source.userId"
            }
        }
    },
    "limit": #if($context.arguments.limit) $context.arguments.limit #else 10 #end,
   "nextToken": #if($context.arguments.nextToken) "$context.arguments.nextToken" #else null #end
}
```

What would be the best practice for implementing this for AuroraServerless/MySQL? Would I write this code within the resolver on AppSync as shown in the documentation, or should this be a Lambda function that is connected to the resolver?

Comment: It's up to you, depending on how you need to construct your query. If you can use VTL to construct the query, then you can build it similarly to how you build it for DynamoDB requests (in fact it's even simpler). Have you read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-rds.html ?

Comment: btw, unrelated, you may want to use `userId: ID!` for your user type

Answer (score 0):

i hope you fixed your problem.

I`m currently in the same situation.

And there's another obstacle when trying to implement this functionality with mysql: Pagination

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3111

Would be great if you could post your resolver once you have fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer, please leave this as a comment instead.